# Flutter popped screen retains values when called again

Tags: flutter

I have a ScreenA with 2 buttons. Button 1 pushes ScreenB(snapshot) and is received as ScreenB(this.snapshot). Button 2 pushes ScreenB(null). Depending on wether snapshot is null or not in ScreenB, different methods are triggered in ScreenB initState.

Now, If I first press Button 2, i.e. ScreenB(null), snapshot is indeed null in ScreenB. But If I press Button1, i.e. ScreenB(snapshot), then pop ScreenB, then press Button2, I would expect snapshot to be null in ScreenB, but it's not.

Am I missing something here? Appreciate some enlightment.

Test Code added as requested:

ScreenA:

```js
import 'screen_b.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'mock_data.dart';
List < MockData > snapshot = List < MockData > ();

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    snapshot.add(MockData("1", "title", "description"));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ScreenA"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: < Widget > [

              Center(child: FlatButton(
                child: Text("Goto ScreenB with null", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB(null)));
                },
              ), ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0), Center(child: FlatButton(
                child: Text("Goto ScreenB with data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB(snapshot[0])));
                },
              ), ),
            ],
          ),
      ), );
  }
}
```

ScreenB:

```js
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'mock_data.dart';

bool editing = false;
class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenB(this._snapshot);
  final MockData _snapshot;

  @override
  _ScreenBState createState() => _ScreenBState();
}

class _ScreenBState extends State < ScreenB > {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget._snapshot != null) {
      editing = true;
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ScreenB"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Center(child: Text("Is Editing: $editing ",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.red)),

          ),
      ), );
  }
}
```

MockData Class:

```js
class MockData {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  MockData(this.id, this.title, this.description);
}
```

To test:
1. run ScreenA and  tap button "Goto ScreenB with null". Text on ScreenB shows "Is Editing: false" as expected.

2. Hit back arrow on appBar to pop ScreenB, then tap "Goto ScreenB with data". Text on ScreenB shows "Is Editing: true" as expected.
3. Repeat 1 and now Text on ScreenB shows "Is Editing: true" as NOT expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is the snaphot that you mentioned here of type AsyncSnapshot , if yes then the data snapshot is never null, the data field of snapshot is what is null

```
snapshot.data == null
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, not AsyncSnapshot. Snapshot from List Object.

Comment: Can you share a gist of the code you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing:

```js
@override
void dispose() {
  editing = false;
  super.dispose();
}
```

in ScreenB. Still puzzled though why the variable keeps the last value, even after the screen has been popped.